# Is it possible to Implement Azure Ad Authentication in webforms without cookie authentication type?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

the below is working code.
But I need to implement the solution without sing coockies (UseCookieAuthentication).
After Azure authentication, when we check the AuthenticationTyoe in Identity it shown as Cookies, which i need to avoid. any suggetions/other implementations

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    );
    }
```

Comment: Arbitrary requirements make it tough for people to recommend a specific approach. Why do you want to achieve this without cookies?

Comment: Well it's what have been requested by customer,  failed to convince even after explaining multiple times the need of cookies for the implementation. Now I need to get it done but couldn't find any other ways so far

Comment: Okay, so what is it then about using cookies that the customer objects to? That way no one wastes their time proposing a solution that violates your customer's requirements.